# Matrix dimension question

Tags: linear-algebra

I came across this equation in a book on financial econometrics.

If $R_t$ is an $N \times 1$ matrix, $B$ is an $N \times K$ matrix, $R_{kt}$ is a $K \times 1$ matrix,   $\gamma_0$ is a scalar

and $\iota$'s dimension is given as 'a conforming vector of ones'

Can I write the following?

\begin{align} R_t = \iota \gamma_0 + B(R_{kt} - \iota \gamma_0)  \end{align}

If so, what is the dimension of $\iota$?

Since $R_t$ is an $N \times 1$ column vector the first term $\iota \gamma_0$ must be $N \times 1$ implying that the dimension of $\iota$ must be $N \times 1$ but since B is $N \times K$ the term $(R_{Kt} - \iota \gamma_0)$ must be $K \times 1$, implying the dimension of $\iota$ is $K \times 1$.

Can $\iota$ be both $N \times 1$ and $K \times 1$ in the same equation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original text seems to use the same notation to denote two different objects.

You might like to introduce a subscript to denote the length of the vector to make things clearer.

\begin{align} R_t = \iota_N \gamma_0 + B(R_{kt} - \iota_K \gamma_0)  \end{align}

Comment: Thanks! So "a conforming vector of ones" means the dimension of that vector will be whatever it needs to be to work, even if it must represent different objects in the same equation.

Comment: from the context, seems to be... though one should try to be precise whenever we can.